# getting update that remote branch has new commit?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-commit

Is there a way in git to get an update new commit has been made to the branch by the user?

I have used a command [git notify](https://github.com/jakeonrails/git-notify), but it only gives notification if user pulls the branch

Comment: There's [git-dude](https://github.com/sickill/git-dude), and I'm guessing others.

Comment: @Biffen So far I tried on my mac and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess a few git clients with a gui will have this option, one of them is [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). It will basically keep checking the repository every so often, in SourceTree by default I think is 10 minutes, configurable.
If you don't want to use these kind of programs, you could create a script to either run it whenever you want to check the repository given a time frequency. For that:
Supposing that origin refers to the repository, you would need to do

```
git fetch origin
```

Then, the remote branch origin/master will contain the snapshot of master in the remote repository. Now, you can compare master and origin/master with

```
git log master...origin/master
```

to see the commits that are only in master or origin/master.

Comment: perfect, I'd go with writing my own script then, since Sourcetree is not available for CentOS .